# How to copy a product's attributes value to another attribute?

Tags: php, product-attribute, html

i want to copy a product's attribute (weight) to another atribute (general_weight).

i found this codes, but i don't know what to do with this codes? or where to copy them?

```
    $prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    $val=$prod->getData('attribute_code');
```

assign the values to another attribute of that product with this code

```
    $prod->setAttreibuteCode($val);

    $prod->save();
```

i will thankful if you experts help me and explain by details.

> ** i want weight attribute value to be copied into general_weight always on product save.

Comment: why you need this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moh3n,i suggest that export an product from Admin in csv format. with sku,weight and then import that csv with change columns name to general_weight from weight.

pragmatically if want then follow below process:

```
 $prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

        $val=$prod->getData('weight');

        $prod->setGeneralWeight($val);

        $prod->save();
```

**Update:**

Create an script at magento  root `update.php` and put the below code :

```
<?php
require_once  "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app("admin");
umask();

/*
 Step2: get Product Collection filter by Saleable
*/
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('weight');

foreach($collection as $product){
$val=$product->getWeight();
/*$product->getWeight() is not given the value then used 

$product->getResource()->getAttribute('weight')->getFrontend()->getValue($product-)

*/
$product->setGeneralWeight($val);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'general_weight');

}
```

then run the script by browser or shell php program.

Comment: where should i copy this code?

Comment: can you please tell me how many product on your system >

Comment: i want weight attribute to be always copied to general_weight on product save. does this code do that?

Comment: about 600 products

Comment: when i run 'update.php' with your code i face this error: 'Fatal error: Call to a member function getWeight() on a non-object in /home/dokanche/public_html/update_weight.php on line 12'

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with a sql query.
But First you need to identify the attribute ids for your attributes and their types.

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id, attribute_code, backend_type
FROM 
    eav_attribute 
WHERE
    attribute_code IN ('weight', 'general_weight') AND
    entity_type_id = (SELECT 
                          entity_type_Id 
                      FROM 
                          eav_entity_type
                      WHERE
                          entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
                     )
```

Let's say it turns out like this:

```
attribute_id|attribute_code|backend_type
101         |weight        |decimal
502         |general_weight|decimal
```

To determine the table for each attribute type you just append `catalog_product_entity_` to the `backend_type`.
So in this case `catalog_product_entity_decimal` is for both of them (and they should be since the attributes should be the same type).

Now run this (backup your database before trying it).Replace 502 and 101 with the ids you got from the query above.:

```
INSERT INTO 
    `catalog_product_entity_decimal` -- the table for `general_weight` attribute
    (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT entity_type_id, 502 as attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value
FROM 
    `catalog_product_entity_decimal` -- the table for `weight` attribute
WHERE 
    attribute_id = 101 -- the id of the weight attribute
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    value = VALUES(value)
```

Now rebuild your indexes.

Comment: Good and faster way

Comment: @AmitBera. And risky :)

Comment: Yes.it is also risky

Answer (score 0):

i have a `Weight` attribute :

```
Attribute Code: weight
Scope: general
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Text Field
Values Required: yes
Apply To: Simple Product, Bundle Product
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend: yes
```

and i have a `General Weight` attribute :

```
Attribute Code: general_weight
Scope: general
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Text Field
Values Required: no
Apply To: All Product Types
Use in Advanced Search: yes
Comparable on Front-end: yse
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend: yes
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end: yes
```

i want to assign `Weight` attribute to `General Weight` without four decimals. i mean i want the value of `Weight` attribute( for example 2000.0000 to copy into `General Weight` value on product save (but without for last decimals like 2000).

**i made an small extension for that in this way:**

i created `Moh3n_Attvaluecopier.xml` file in `app/etc/modules` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and `config.xml` file in `app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/etc` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <moh3nattvaluecopier>
                <class>Attvaluecopier_Model</class>
            </moh3nattvaluecopier>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>copyAttribute</method>
                    </moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

and `Observer.php` file in `app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/model` with this content:

```
<?php

class Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer
{

public function  copyAttribute($observer){

    if(!$this->_processFlag):

        $this->_processFlag=true;
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();
        $_productid = $_product->getId();
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $loadCurrentProduct = $productModel->load($_productid);
        $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight(intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight()));
        $loadCurrentProduct->save();
        endif;}
    }
```

Comment: This code is so imperformant... Take a look at Amit his code to save the attribute, it's 10 times as fast, Marius his answer is even faster but is risky if you don't know what you are doing :). This is not the correct answer.