# how to add a prefix to a product attribute value?

Tags: php, product-attribute, html

how to add a prefix to a product attribute value?.
i want to add a prefix to a product attribute.
for example: i have an attribute named `general_weight` with a number value: `1000` . i want to add a prefix like: `Kg` to its value. i want it to be shown this way:

`General Weight: 1000 Kg` .

how to do that?
i will thankful if you experts help me with this.

Comment: If it's a custom attribute why not use a text field that accepts the value 1000 kg

Comment: its a copy of weight att

Comment: I guss that you want this type of works.. if you will put the weight value of product is 100 then in general_weight attribute you want it value to 100KG

Comment: @AmitBera yes exactly. i did copy the attribute value in this way [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute/54930#54930) but the problem is prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

observer.php should be like this:

```
<?php

class Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer
{

public function  copyAttribute($observer){

    if(!$this->_processFlag):

        $this->_processFlag=true;
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();
        $_productid = $_product->getId();
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $loadCurrentProduct = $productModel->load($_productid);
        $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight(intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight()));
        $weight = intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight());
        $gw = (string)$weight. " KG";
        $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight($gw);
        $loadCurrentProduct->save();
        endif;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `magento event/observer`.There are lot of events are exiting in by whose you can set  `general_weight basic of weight`.

As you have using [this code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute/54930#54930).There some  issue in your observer.

**Don't need to load the product object Again**

```
  <?php
class Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer
{
    public function copyAttribute($observer)
    {
        $finalTemWeight=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getData('weight');
        $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->setData('general_weight',$finalTemWeight.'KG');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: it gets this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_product' (T_VARIABLE) in app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/Model/Observer.php on line 8

Comment: please ckd. the code it.............

Comment: again error :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_product' (T_VARIABLE) in app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/Model/Observer.php on line 7

Comment: i  cannot understand d why it not save KG value

Comment: oops! i made a mistake. it doesn't save whole value!

Comment: please accept my asnwer

Comment: as i said in may last comment, your method is not working. its not saving any thing to `general_weight` attribute even the number!

Comment: Hi. I have ckhd on my system.. It is Woking. Do not know why it not... Your system

Comment: i replaced my observer.php with your code. is that all i should do? or i missed some thing?