# Copy a customer-attribute value into another one programmatically

Tags: event-observer, customer-address, customer-attribute

i have a customer attribute with id: `mobile`, which is a required field in account creation. i want an observer to copy mobile attribute value into Magento default `_address_telephone` attribute automatically on account creation.

how should its `observer.php` and `config.xml` be?

I did it for product attribute this way: [How to copy a product's attributes value to another attribute?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute/54930#54930)

Comment: Did you try out Jeroen's solution? It should work

Answer (score 2):

Your observer should have a function

```
public function moveMobileTo($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

    // If you mean this, the next line applies
    $customer->setData('_address_telephone', $customer->getData('mobile'));

    // If you mean this, the next line applies
    $address = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
    $address->setData('telephone', $customer->getData('mobile'));
}
```

You should listen to the `customer_save_before` event.

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  [...]
  <global>
    <events>
      <customer_save_before>
        <observers>
          <[namespace]_[module]_customer_save_before>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>moveMobileTo</method>
          </[namespace]_[module]_customer_save_before>
        </observers>
      </customer_save_before>     
    </events>
  </global>
  [...]
</config>
```