# observer.php won't work after magento local to live migration

Tags: php, event-observer, product-attribute, html, migration

i have this `Observer.php` file in `app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/model` to copy a product attribute value into another product  attribute on product save:

```
<?php

class Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer
{

public function  copyAttribute($observer){

    if(!$this->_processFlag):

        $this->_processFlag=true;
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();
        $_productid = $_product->getId();
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $loadCurrentProduct = $productModel->load($_productid);
        $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight(intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight()));
        $weight = intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight());
        $gw = (string)$weight. " KG";
        $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight($gw);
        $loadCurrentProduct->save();
        endif;}
    }
```

i created `Moh3n_Attvaluecopier.xml` file in `app/etc/modules` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and `config.xml` file in `app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/etc` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <moh3nattvaluecopier>
                <class>Attvaluecopier_Model</class>
            </moh3nattvaluecopier>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>copyAttribute</method>
                    </moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

full extension link: [How to copy a product's attributes value to another attribute?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute)

it was working fine on localserver but after i migrated magento from local to online server it wont work. no error, no log. it wont copy the value.

Comment: Please share the part of config.xml which registers this event observer, and/or the code that calls it.

Comment: @TylerV. check my question again please. its updated

Comment: Sounds like an uncleared cache on the online server.

Comment: @TylerV. you mean every thing is alright with this extension, yah?

Comment: It looks fine, though I haven't run it. But the hunch that I have if it worked in one environment but not another is that either 1) The new attribute doesn't exist on the new environment, or 2) The cache wasn't cleared, so Magento isn't aware of the new observer.

Comment: I hope model is a type, because Linux servers are case sensitive on file/directory names. So if you develop on your local WIndows machine it works just fine. If you copy it to the Linuxserver it suddenly doesn't work because of this difference.

Comment: @Jeroen i have created it in a magento which was running in Ampps on Macosx. can you explain more what can i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try updating your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <attvaluecopier>
                <class>Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model</class>
            </attvaluecopier>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>attvaluecopier/observer</class>
                        <method>copyAttribute</method>
                    </moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Check if your directories are spelled correctly `Mohen/Attvaluecopier/Model/Observer.php`

Check if compilation is disabled before installing the module `System / Tools / Compilation`